# jQuery children of event.toElement object

Tags: jquery, selector, draggable, helper, children

I have a draggable object in jQuery with "helper: 'clone'". I have used $(event.toElement) to create the selector to manipulate that draggable object. I would like to be able to select the children of that object but using .children() does not return any child objects. I want to be able to attach the *tinymce* function to the textrea of the dragged object, not the div.

My draggable object is:

```
<div class="text" style="padding: 10px"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
.draggable({helper: "clone", revert: "invalid", stop: function(event, ui){          
    $(event.toElement).children().tinymce({script_url : 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'});
```

How can I get an instance of the textarea from the draggable object?

Many thanks

Comment: Just give the textarea an id then select it

Comment: I'm not really familiar with drag and drop with jQuery, but one quick idea: Does  `event.toElement` really contain the element you expect? What does `alert(event.toElement.nodeName)` show?

Comment: with element inspector, using the console, the highlighted object is the newly created dragged object. I did something similar to Musa but instead used classes.